# Nautilus link in the desktop do not open anymore

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, desktop-icons

I've tried to research here but I haven't found anything similar to my issue, and other solutions that I've found around helped only temporarily.

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and all works fine, I set up in the Gnome Tweaks to have the Home and Wastebin visible on my desktop and they did work as expected for a while, but then I did a terrible mistake, I right click on the Home shortcut and "somehow" set them to open with the text editor, and now I'm not able to open them again, I removed the association with Gedit, and also tried to associate them with the entry called Files, but still not working.

If I try to disable the shortcuts with Tweak, then set it to no show anything on the desktop, and then switch them back on, it will work for a couple of times and then nothing again. I notice that those icons are seen by the Open With window as "Nautilus-links" rather than folders, what should I associate them with?

It's my first post hopefully I've been clear enough as English is not even my first language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you right-click on that dysfunctional launcher icon on the desktop again, a context menu will appear. In this context menu there should be an item called "Allow launching". Click that item. The Nautilus icon should change to the correct icon, and it should work as intended, thereafter.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have that option, I don't think they are actual launchers, the options I have by right-clicking are just to open, open in a new tab, open in a new window, open with another application, rename, open in the terminal, and properties